# Images for Multiple Screen Densities on React Native

Tags: android, performance, react-native, android-app-bundle

[React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images.html) told:

> You can also use the @2x and @3x suffixes to provide images for different screen densities. If you have the following file structure:

```
.
├── button.js
└── img
    ├── check.png
    ├── check@2x.png
    └── check@3x.png
```

> the bundler will bundle and serve the image corresponding to device's screen density.

And [Android App Bundle Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#aab_format) told,

> Google Play then uses the app bundle to generate the various APKs that are served to users, such as the base APK, dynamic feature APKs, configuration APKs, and (for devices that do not support split APKs) multi-APKs. 
>   [image: AAB Result]

I have multiple images that support different screen densities (`img.png`, `img@2x.png`, etc). If I build application in `.aab` format, did my different-screen-densities-images will be separated and placed on different asset pack based on screen densities?

Comment: In short yes. React Native only provides a convenient shortcut so you don't have to place yourself the files under the directories hdpi, xhdpi, etc. but will do it for you. Then in the App Bundle they will be placed correctly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, @Pierre.

I think so. But, how do you prove it?

I've created project with `{image.png, image@2x.png, image@3x.png}`, built `.aab`, extracted to device-specific `.apks`, then unzipped. But, I cannot find my image in my apks.

Any idea to prove that?

Comment: `{image.png: 1kb, image@2x.png: 2kb, image@3x.png: 2.5mb}` that is my images with size details. I built `.aab`, create many device spec json different by screen densities (from mdpi, to xxxhdpi), extracted to many `apks` based on all device spec json file, then I compared all `apks` file size. It turns out all `apks` has same size in total. No difference at all.

Comment: But, when I put those images to android native code folder (`drawable-[screendensities]`) , it resulted different size `apks`. 

> did my different-screen-densities-images will be separated and placed on different asset pack based on screen densities
the answer is no, it didn't

Comment: Not for assets, but for resources yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> did my different-screen-densities-images will be separated and placed on different asset/resource pack based on screen densities?

the answer is no, it didn't.

This is my step I've done:
1. Created fresh project as experiment
2. Put some images on JS Codebase `{image.png: 1kb, image@2x.png: 2kb, image@3x.png: 2.5mb}`
3. Built `.aab`
4. Created many phone spec json file
5. Extracted `.aab` to `.apks` as many as phone spec json files
6. Compare total size of all `.apks` created

It resulted same total size. I expected significant difference of total file size on xxxhdpi `.apks`. But it din't.

Then, I intrigued to tried another experiment.

I moved all images from JS Codebase to Android Native Codebase (drawable-xxx dir). I do step 2-6.

It resulted difference total size. xxxhdpi `.apks` has significantly bigger file size than the other